# std::find_if map to object

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Should I use example 1 or example 2 for map pointer from find_if to object
Which one is the best?

```
struct test {
 INT id
}

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<test>> vec;

int ID = 75;

auto obj = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&ID](std::shared_ptr<test>& r){
 return r->id == ID;
});

if ( obj != vec.end() ) {
 // example 1
 std::shared_ptr<test> example1 = (*obj);

 // example 2 by reference
 std::shared_ptr<test>& example2 = (*obj);
}
```

Comment: It depends on how you are going to use it later.

Comment: If your vector ain't modified during the usage, use `const &`

Comment: I have problem on example1. I modified by example1->id = 2: exception are throw sometimes even obj is found. I run as debugger Could it be memory corruption?

Comment: Share your code that caught said exception. I feel like it's not a *complete* example. Read carefully about [mcve].

Comment: "Best" in what way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will not modify `vec` between the call to `find_if` and the usage of the `shared_ptr`, then take a reference to the element as in `example2` to avoid unnecessary adjustments to the reference count. If you cannot be sure that this is the case, then copy the `shared_ptr` by value, as in `example`.